# How to guarantee type safety with multiple maps and multiple enums as their keys?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm looking to create a type-safe function to retrieve a value from a map. There is logic triggering inside of my use case of the function, hence the need for the function outside of this trivial example below:

```
enum ExampleA {
    A = 'A'
}

enum ExampleB {
    B = 'B'
}

const mapA = {
    [ExampleA.A]: 'a'
};

const mapB = {
    [ExampleB.B]: 'b'
};

type AllMaps = typeof mapA | typeof mapB;
type AllKeys = ExampleA | ExampleB;

// type error below due to the key obviously not existing on both maps
const typeSafeMapValueGetter = (map: AllMaps, key: AllKeys) => map[key];

typeSafeMapValueGetter(mapA, ExampleA.A);
```

I'm a bit stumped on how to continue here, I wanted to avoid using generics to force the developer to pass in which map and key type they are utilizing. However, if there is a way to apply generics to let Typescript infer the expected key type based on the given map type, that would seem like the desired approach. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in front of me, I made the mistake of explicitly typing out the possible maps and keys, when generics solved this. For anyone potentially reading this:

```
function typeSafeMapGetter<T>(map: T, key: keyof T) {
    return map[key];
}
```